How to make a generic DataGrid using RenderFragment
I have been trying several times now to use the DataGrid example from the website, and create a generic component so that the functionality in that can be reproduced and contained in the usecase of having several tables for simple data CRUD. I can not get it to work and it's becomming a huge frustration point. Can anyone take a look at this and tell me what am I missing? It's almost working appart from the fact that the render fragment itself is not being rendered for whatever reason.
This would be the markup file:
@typeparam TItem where TItem : new()
@inherits DataGridRazor<TItem>

<style>
    .rz-grid-table {
        width: unset;
    }
</style>


<RadzenStack Orientation="Orientation.Horizontal" AlignItems="AlignItems.Center" Gap="10px" class="mt-2 mb-4">
<RadzenButton ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Success" Icon="add_circle_outline" Text="Add New Order" Click="@InsertRow"/>

<RadzenDataGrid @ref="itemsGrid" AllowAlternatingRows="false" AllowFiltering="true" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5" AllowSorting="true" EditMode="DataGridEditMode.Single"
            Data="@Model.items" TItem="TItem" RowUpdate="@OnUpdateRow" RowCreate="@OnCreateRow" Sort="@Reset" Page="@Reset" Filter="@Reset" ColumnWidth="200px">
<Columns>
    @foreach (var item in Model.items)
    {
        @ColumnsTemplate(item)
    }
</Columns>

And this would be the code behind:
public class DataGridModel<TItem>
{
    internal IEnumerable<TItem> items { get; set; } = new List<TItem>();
    public List<TItem> ItemsToInsert { get; set; } = new List<TItem>();
    public List<TItem> ItemsToUpdate { get; set; } = new List<TItem>();
}

public class DataGridRazor<TItem> : ComponentBase where TItem : new()
{
    [Inject] public IMediator Mediator { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public required Func<TItem, Task> SendCreateItemCommand { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public required Func<TItem, Task> SendUpdateItemCommand { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public required Func<TItem, Task> SendDeleteItemCommand { get; set; }

// Parameter functions for getting the data
[Parameter] public required Func<Task<IEnumerable<TItem>>> GetItems { get; set; }

[Parameter] public RenderFragment<TItem> ColumnsTemplate { get; set; }


protected RadzenDataGrid<TItem> itemsGrid;
protected DataGridModel<TItem?> Model = new DataGridModel<TItem?>();

protected void Reset()
{
    Guard.Against.Null(Model, nameof(Model));
    Model.ItemsToInsert.Clear();
    Model.ItemsToUpdate.Clear();
}

protected void Reset(TItem? item)
{
    Guard.Against.Null(Model, nameof(Model));
    Model.ItemsToInsert.Remove(item);
    Model.ItemsToUpdate.Remove(item);
}

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    Guard.Against.Null(Mediator, nameof(Mediator));
    await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    await LoadData();
}

private async Task LoadData()
{
    Model.items = await GetItems();
}

private async Task ReloadGrid()
{
    await LoadData();
    await itemsGrid.Reload();
}

protected async Task EditRow(TItem? item)
{
    if (Model.ItemsToInsert.Count() > 0)
    {
        Reset();
    }

    Model.ItemsToUpdate.Add(item);
    await itemsGrid.EditRow(item);
}

protected async void OnUpdateRow(TItem item)
{
    Reset(item);
    await SendUpdateItemCommand(item);
    await ReloadGrid();
}

protected async Task SaveRow(TItem item)
{
    await itemsGrid.UpdateRow(item);
}

protected void CancelEdit(TItem? item)
{
    Reset(item);
    itemsGrid.CancelEditRow(item);
}

protected async Task DeleteRow(TItem? item)
{
    Reset(item);

    if (Model.items.Contains(item))
    {
        await SendDeleteItemCommand(item);
        await ReloadGrid();
    }
    else
    {
        itemsGrid.CancelEditRow(item);
        await ReloadGrid();
    }
}

protected async Task InsertRow()
{
    Reset();
    
    var item = new TItem();
    Model.ItemsToInsert.Add(item);
    await itemsGrid.InsertRow(item);
}

protected async Task OnCreateRow(TItem? item)
{
    await SendCreateItemCommand(item);
    Model.ItemsToInsert.Remove(item);
}
}

